# Unable to set a option selected by default in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

I've tried all available solutions and unable to get this simple thing working.

This is my ts file.

```
options = [
    { value: '', label: 'Age group' },
    { value: '2-3', label: '2 to 3 years' },
    { value: '3-4', label: '3 to 4 years' },
    { value: '4-6', label: '4 to 6 years' },
    { value: '6-8', label: '6 to 8 years' },
    { value: '8-12', label: '8 to 12 years' },
  ];

  selectedValue: any = "6-8";
```

Here is my HTML

```
<"form-inline waves-light ml-auto d-lg-none d-sm-flex" mdbWavesEffect>
   <div class="md-form my-0">
      <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="ageGroup" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
        <option value={{option.value}} *ngFor="let option of options">
            {{option.label}}
        </option>
      </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is the output preview.
[image: Output Preview]

This is selecting last option no matter what method I use.

Comment: I tried same code in my system and it just worked fine. Could you please check if in any of the life cycle hook of Angular(For example: ngOninit) you are overriding the value. And could you please share the correct HTML as it is giving some error.

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gejbd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Change the name property to "selectedValue".

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1jb6f7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
<select id="duration" name="duration" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let duration of options" [ngValue]="duration.value"> 
        {{ duration.label }}
  </option>
</select>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-noipl2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1jb6f7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `[value]="option.id"` instead of `value="{{ option.id }}"` in mat-option

Html:

```
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">{{ option.name }} 
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Ts:

```
 selectedValue = this.options[4].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
  <select id="duration" name="duration" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">

     <option *ngFor="let duration of options" [ngValue]="duration.value"> 
        {{ duration.label }}
        </option>

 </select>
```

TypeScript Code:

```
this.selectedValue = this.options[4].id;
```